# Raising the limit of Instafeed's feed request

Tags: javascript, instagram, instafeedjs

I am trying to pull images from an instagram user using Instafeed.js, but Instagram seems to be limiting this pull request to only the 20 most recent posts. I am trying, with no success so far, to raise this limit. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I am using the following script right now, but the "limit" parameter does not work (i.e. only 20 images are returned).

I have added a button to allow pagination, which works, but, once again, only up to the limit of 20 images. I.e. the script will first load 5 images, then I can press the button 3 times, which will load 5 more images at a time, up to the limit of 20.

```
<button id="button">button</button>
<div id="instafeed"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var userFeed = new Instafeed({
get: 'user',
limit: 5,
userId: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
sortBy: 'most-recent',
accessToken: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
});
jQuery('#button').on('click', function() {
userFeed.next();
});
userFeed.run();
</script>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to have a look at the pagination options for Instafeed.js.

Looks to be as simple as calling `userFeed.next()`

Comment: thank you, I will check that option – I intend to load up to 60 results at one time (i.e. without user needing to press a button to load more; and I thought that pagination was only for that purpose, but I will check it out now

Comment: I have added more details. I have managed to get the pagination working with a button, but only up to the limit of 20 images.

Answer (score 1):

Instagram API usage terms have changed. Applications will start in sandbox mode, which have limits, including:

"Data is restricted to the 10 users and the 20 most recent media from each of those users" (https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/).

So the limit of 20 images is caused by this limitation.